# How do I select a random value from an enumeration?

Tags: c#, random, enums

Given an arbitrary enumeration in C#, how do I select a random value?

(I did not find this very basic question on SO. I'll post my answer in a minute as reference for anyone, but please feel free to post your own answer.)

Answer (score 358, accepted):

```
Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Bar));
Random random = new Random();
Bar randomBar = (Bar)values.GetValue(random.Next(values.Length));
```

Comment: Make sure you don't keep recreating `random` in a tight loop though - otherwise you'll keep getting the same value.

Comment: Should that be random.Next(values.Length -1)?

Comment: @uriDium No, the argument specifies which value is the first to be too big to be returned (i.e. _max minus 1_)

Comment: values.Length *- 1*

Comment: DarinDimitrov IMO the first comment by @ChrisF should be a note inside the answer with credit to Chris.

Comment: Heads up you need to subtract  the length -1

Comment: You do not need to subtract anything. Random.Next() returns a random integer that is *less* than the specified maximum. If you subtract, you will never get the last value in the enum.

Answer (score 83):

Use Enum.GetValues to retrieve an array of all values. Then select a random array item.

```
static Random _R = new Random ();
static T RandomEnumValue<T> ()
{
    var v = Enum.GetValues (typeof (T));
    return (T) v.GetValue (_R.Next(v.Length));
}
```

Test:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var value = RandomEnumValue<System.DayOfWeek> ();
    Console.WriteLine (value.ToString ());
}
```

->

```
Tuesday
Saturday
Wednesday
Monday
Friday
Saturday
Saturday
Saturday
Friday
Wednesday
```

Comment: `GetValues` now supports a type hint. `Enum.GetValues<T>()`, even neater.

Comment: With `static T RandomEnumValue<T> ()` **`where T : Enum`** you can limit the generic types to only `Enum`. Otherwise you could pass any type... ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786774/in-c-sharp-what-does-where-t-class-mean))

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative version as an `Extension Method` using `LINQ`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static Enum GetRandomEnumValue(this Type t)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(t)          // get values from Type provided
            .OfType<Enum>()               // casts to Enum
            .OrderBy(e => Guid.NewGuid()) // mess with order of results
            .FirstOrDefault();            // take first item in result
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public enum SomeEnum
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
        Three = 3,
        Four = 4
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(SomeEnum).GetRandomEnumValue());
        }
    }           
}
```

> Two 
>   One 
>   Four 
>   Four 
>   Four 
>   Three 
>   Two 
>   Four 
>   One 
>   Three

Comment: You could also make it an extension: `public static T GetRandomEnumValue<T>() where T : Enum => (T) Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<Enum>().OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();` That simplifies its usage to: `GetRandomEnumValue<EnumType>()`

Comment: I downvoted this question because it's not made clear why you would you generate N random GUIDs and then go through the trouble of sorting them, in light of a simple randomized index, which would've sufficed.

Comment: @kerzek This is an extension and has a specified type! He limited it with `where T : Enum` to only enums.

Answer (score 7):

Adapted as a Random class extension:

```cs
public static class RandomExtensions
{   
    public static T NextEnum<T>(this Random random)
        where T : struct, Enum
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues<T>();

        return values[random.Next(values.Length)];
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```cs
var random = new Random();
var myEnumRandom = random.NextEnum<MyEnum>();
```

Comment: Great solution. I have updated the code to use modern C#.

Answer (score 5):

You could just do this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
return (MyEnum) rnd.Next(Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length);
```

No need to store arrays

Comment: `GetNames` returns an array.

Comment: I meant that you don't need to store it. My bad

Comment: If somebody is doing this in a loop they would call GetNames every time instead of caching it in an array. This would slow their code down so I don't see what's your contribution here?

Comment: @BojidarStanchev **IF**, in my case this works wonderful, thank you Breno :)

Comment: @BojidarStanchev Your implied scenario of someone copy pasting this in a loop without adapting the code to their use case isn't a problem of the answer or the question, it's your own problem of misapplying the solution.

Comment: Works only if the enums are incremental, no-go for enums with assigned values.

Answer (score 4):

Call `Enum.GetValues`; this returns an array that represents all possible values for your enum. Pick a random item from this array. Cast that item back to the original enum type.

Answer (score 3):

The modern answer combining [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3132139/7032856) and [its comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132126/how-do-i-select-a-random-value-from-an-enumeration#comment122403399_3132139):

```
var randomMyEnum = GetRandom<MyEnum>();
```

the implementation:

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    private static Random Random = new Random();

    public static T GetRandom<T>() where T : struct, Enum
    {
        T[]? v = Enum.GetValues<T>();
        return (T)v.GetValue(Random.Next(v.Length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic function for it.
Keep the RNG creation outside the high frequency code.

```
public static Random RNG = new Random();

public static T RandomEnum<T>()
{  
    Type type = typeof(T);
    Array values = Enum.GetValues(type);
    lock(RNG)
    {
        object value= values.GetValue(RNG.Next(values.Length));
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Keys randomKey = RandomEnum<System.Windows.Forms.Keys>();
```

Comment: Having a static method which isn't threadsafe is pretty dangerous.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You're right. Random.Next() is not threadsafe and will start returning zeroes when it breaks. I've updated my answer based on this info.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these answers are pretty old and - correct me if I'm wrong - seem to work with some sketchy concepts like type erasure and dynamic type casting. However, as user Yarek T points out, there's no need for that with the [generic overload of `Enum.GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0#system-enum-getvalues-1):

```cs
static Random random = new Random();

// Somewhat unintuitively, we need to constrain the type parameter to
// both struct *and* Enum - struct is required b/c the type can't be
// nullable, and Enum is required b/c GetValues expects an Enum type.
// You'd think that Enum itself would satisfy the non-nullable
// constraint, but alas, me compiler tells me otherwise - perhaps
// someone more knowledgeable can explain why this is in a comment?
static TEnum RandomEnumValue<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    TEnum[] vals = Enum.GetValues<TEnum>();
    return vals[random.Next(vals.Length)];
}
```

Or, like in [borja garcia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60847339/4661269), we can even write this as an extension of the random class

```cs
public static class RandomExtensions
{   
    public static TEnum NextEnumValue<TEnum>(this Random random)
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        TEnum[] vals = Enum.GetValues<TEnum>();
        return vals[random.Next(vals.Length)];
    }
}
```

And we can run the same test from [mafu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3132139/4661269):

```cs
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var day = random.NextEnumValue<System.DayOfWeek>();
    Console.WriteLine(day.ToString());
}
```

Potential output:

```
Thursday
Saturday
Sunday
Sunday
Sunday
Saturday
Wednesday
Monday
Wednesday
Thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm a fan of extension methods, so I would use something like this (while not really an extension, it looks similar):

```
public enum Options {
    Zero,
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
}

public static class RandomEnum {
    private static Random _Random = new Random(Environment.TickCount);

    public static T Of<T>() {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Must use Enum type");

        Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        return (T)enumValues.GetValue(_Random.Next(enumValues.Length));
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class RandomTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        Options option;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            option = RandomEnum.Of<Options>();
            Console.WriteLine(option);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As of C#7.3 you can constraint your generic type to be an enum: `public static T Of<T>() where T : Enum`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes#csharp

Answer (score -1):

You can also cast a random value:

```cs
using System;

enum Test {
  Value1,
  Value2,
  Value3
}

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var max = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test)).Length;
    var value = (Test)new Random().Next(0, max - 1);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
  }
}
```

But you should use a better *randomizer* like the one in this [library](https://github.com/gsscoder/csharpx) of mine.

Comment: Gah, almost. This fails for non-auto numbered enums. GetValues return you a list, Its safe to select a random element from that.