# In c# what does 'where T : class' mean?

Tags: c#, syntax

In C# what does `where T : class` mean?

Ie.

```
public IList<T> DoThis<T>() where T : class
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Simply put this is constraining the generic parameter to a class (or more specifically a reference type which could be a class, interface, delegate, or array type).

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for further details.

Comment: You missed one case. The type argument for T can also be *any other type parameter that is constrained to be a reference type*.

Answer (score 62):

It's a type constraint on `T`, specifying that it must be a class.

The `where` clause can be used to specify other type constraints, e.g.:

```
where T : struct // T must be a struct
where T : new()  // T must have a default parameterless constructor
where T : IComparable // T must implement the IComparable interface
```

For more information, check out Microsoft's page [generic parameter constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

Comment: It is possible to combine these together, e.g: `where T : class, IComparable, new()`

Comment: `must be a class`? What about interface? If what `class` word does mean is explained, the concept can be grasped. Or, it is a defect.

Answer (score 45):

It is a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). In this case it means that the generic type `T` has to be a reference type (class, interface, delegate, or array type).

Answer (score 19):

That restricts `T` to *reference types*. You won't be able to put value types (`struct`s and primitive types except `string`) there.

Comment: This answer (and a couple of other with the same information) was more useful for me than the selected one, because it gives an example of what T cannot be (I was wondering what this constraint actually added to the story)

Answer (score 11):

`where T: class`  literally means that ***`T has to be a class`***. It can be any reference type. Now whenever any code calls your `DoThis<T>()` method it must provide a class to replace **T**. For example if I were to call your `DoThis<T>()` method then I will have to call it like following:

```
DoThis<MyClass>();
```

If your metthod is like like the following:

```
public IList<T> DoThis<T>() where T : class
{
   T variablename = new T();

   // other uses of T as a type

}
```

Then where ever T appears in your method, it will be replaced by MyClass. So the final method that the compiler calls , will look like the following:

```
public IList<MyClass> DoThis<MyClass>() 
{
   MyClass variablename= new MyClass();

  //other uses of MyClass as a type

  // all occurences of T will similarly be replace by MyClass
 }
```

Comment: -1: `new T()` is not possible with `where T : class`. you have to specify `where T: new()` to be allowed to do it.

Comment: @explorer can we define a single generic method and call it from multiple places to insert a record by passing different parameter's from different places.

Answer (score 9):

it means that the type used as `T` when the generic method is used must be a class - i.e. it cannot be a struct or built in number like `int` or `double`

```
// Valid:
var myStringList = DoThis<string>();
// Invalid - compile error
var myIntList = DoThis<int>();
```

Answer (score 4):

It is called a type parameter constraint. Effectively it constraints what type T can be.

> The type argument must be a reference
>   type; this applies also to any class,
>   interface, delegate, or array type.

[Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

T represents an object type of, it implies that you can give any type of.
IList : if IList s=new IList;
Now s.add("Always accept string.").

Answer (score 3):

Here T refers to a Class.It can be a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

'T' represents a generic type. It means it can accept any type of class. The following article might help:

```
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031024.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T : SomeType
{
    // Class implementation
}
```

Type Constraints: You can apply various constraints to type parameters, such as:

**Class constraint (where T : class):** This ensures that the type argument must be a reference type (a class or interface).

**Struct constraint (where T : struct):** This ensures that the type argument must be a value type (a struct).

**Constructor constraint (where T : new()):** This ensures that the type argument must have a parameterless constructor.

**Interface constraint (where T : IMyInterface):** This ensures that the type argument must implement a specific interface.

**Base class constraint (where T : MyBaseClass):** This ensures that the type argument must inherit from a specific base class.