# Extension Method on enum parameter must be constrained to a struct

Tags: c#, enums, type-constraints

I've seen some code https://stackoverflow.com/a/479417/1221410

It is designed to take an enum value and get the description. The relevant part is:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue) where T : struct
```

I'm using the same code but what has confused me is I can't change the constraint

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue) where T : enum

public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue) where T : class
```

2 issue have arisen from this.

The first is when I use the `enum` as the constraint parameter. This should [constrain the generic parameter to an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786774/in-c-sharp-what-does-where-t-class-mean). If so, why can't I type code like

```
var a = "hello world";
```

within the function. That has nothing to do with the parameter...

My second question is, when I change the constraint to `class`, then the above code snippet (`var a = "hello world";`) works fine but when I call the function I get the error message

```
'Enum.Result' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GetDescription<T>(T)'
```

`Enum.Result must be a reference type`... I thought a class was a reference type...

Why does the example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/479417/1221410  only work with `struct`?

Comment: You are getting that error because an enum is not a class, it is a struct.

Comment: All enums are structs, so `where T : struct` will work with enums. `where T : enum` is simply not valid C# syntax. (but we all hope that will change some day)

Comment: `where T : enum` is not a valid constraint, and all enums are structs so you can't use `where T : class`. Why do you need to change the constraint at all?

Comment: What is this `Enum.Result` and how does `var a = "hello world";` fit in with all this?

Comment: @Lee, I don't *need* to, but if I don't then I won't understand or run into these type of issues... I would have continued not understanding it. By breaking stuff I can try to fix it. When I can't fix it, I can research. When research doesn't fix it, StackOverflow does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem why `T : class` won't work is because an enum always is a struct. So you see it the wrong way. You write:

> Enum.Result must be a reference type... I thought a class was a
>   reference type...

You are right that a class is a reference type. But `Enum.Result` isn't a class. It's a struct as mentioned above. Your constraint `T : class` just accept a reference type.

Further you can't type `var a = "hello world";` in your function if you change constraint to `T : enum`, because this constraint isn't valid. So you wouldn't be able to write any valid code in your method before you fix your constraint.

Take a look at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/d5x73970.aspx) for clarify which constraints are possible.

Comment: Link to english https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, enum is not a class.
However, Enum is. It's just a special one and if you try to constrain the type like that, it won't let you:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue) where T : Enum
```

> Constraint cannot be special class 'Enum'

The existing code from the question you linked is about the best you can do but see here if you want more info: [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

As to the second part of your question, about constraining it to 'class' instead, there must be something else going on there.

Edit - I'm dumb - what Sebi said. :)

There is no Enum.Result in either your code snippets or the answer you linked to so I think we'll need to see more of your code to answer that one.