# In c# what does 'where T : class?' mean

Tags: c#, syntax

In C# what does `where T : class?` mean (note the question mark on the end of the class constraint)

For instance

```cs
public IList<T> DoThis<T>() where T : class?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In c# what does 'where T : class' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786774/in-c-sharp-what-does-where-t-class-mean)

Comment: The `?` addresses nullable reference types. I do not think this should have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: this is a legitimate question and not a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` attached to a type in C# (supported from version 8) means it is a [nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types). `class?` means that the calling code has to pass in a type parameter which is a `class`, and may be nullable.

For instance, `DoThis<string?>(someNullableString)` is valid. It may also be called with the non-nullable version, e.g. `DoThis<string>(someNonNullableString)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid syntax for C# 8.  The syntax constrains `T` to be a [nullable reference type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen some things mentioned.  And it's a bit counter-intuitive at first since we all know reference types *can* be null.  This feature really answers *should* they be null.

"Nullable reference type" basically states your intent that null is a valid value, both to those reading the code and to the compiler.

It helps to protect you from doing things like `string shouldntBeNull = null;`.

Which you can spot if you enable this feature using `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the project settings.

In contrast, this shows intent more clearly `string? couldBeNull = null;`

This is an opt-in feature.