# Picking a random enum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, faker

I've created a simpel model like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Resa.Models
{
public enum GenderType : byte {
    Unknown = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    NotApplicable = 9
}

public class Profile
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; } // temporary
    public Nullable<DateTime> DayOfBirth { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt { get; set; }

    public List<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

}

So I started mapping my model in a DbContext. But now I want to seed it with Bogus and Faker. Gendertype is an Enum and i'd like to generate 1 out of those 3.

This is my code so far for the seeding:

```
if(!context.Profiles.Any())
            {
                // Dates to generate random dates
                DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
                DateTime end = new DateTime(1998, 1, 1);

                var faker = new Bogus.DataSets.Name();
                var profileSkeleton = new Faker<Profile>()
                    .RuleFor(p => p.FirstName, f => faker.FirstName())
                    .RuleFor(p => p.SurName, f => faker.LastName())
                    //.RuleFor(p => p.Gender , )
                    .RuleFor(p => p.DayOfBirth, f => f.Date.Between(start, end))
                    .RuleFor(p => p.Verified, f => true)
                    .RuleFor(p => p.Picture, f => f.Image.People());

                var profiles = new List<Profile>();
                for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    var profile = profileSkeleton.Generate();
                    profiles.Add(profile);
                }
                context.Profiles.AddRange(profiles);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

So the question is: how do I pick a random enum without violating the gendertype?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132126/how-do-i-select-a-random-value-from-an-enumeration ?

Comment: Yes helped me perfectly, I couldn't find it at first, thanks for helping!

Comment: In case someone else is not satisfied by the above answers.

.RuleFor(x => x.EnumType, new Randomizer().Enum<EnumType>())